# Gatsby Graph-ql selection of subfields error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm tyring to make my own site using Gatsby. It's first time to use graph-ql, I made a query with graph-ql ide served by Gatsby for collect SiteMeatadata

```js
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query SiteInformationQuery {
      __typename
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          author {
            name
            summary
          }
          title
          description
        }
      }
    }
  `);
```

I predicted that it returns like

```
{
  "data": {
    "site": {
      "siteMetadata": {
        "title": "Gatsby Typewriter theme",
        "author": {
          "name": "dodok8",
          "summary" : "student"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it made a error.

```sh
 ERROR #85901  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Field "author" of type "SiteSiteMetadataAuthor" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "author { ... }"?

File: src\components\seo.js:21:13
```

But I enviced all subfileds of `author` in query. What's wrong with my subfields and a query sentence?

It's raw data about siteMetadata stored in `gatsby-config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Typewriter theme`,
    description: `Demo page of Gatsby Typewriter theme`,
    author: {
      name: 'dodok8',
      summary: 'student',
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not in the query I wrote, basic query in `componets/seo.js`. There is a query in line 13 if you don't edit this file,

```
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );
```

In my case, I add subfield to author, so I should change it like

```
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author {
              name
              summary
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my

> src/hooks/use-site-metadata.jsx

I added

```
author {
          name,
          twitter,
          summary
        }
```

and it worked for me.